# Row Label being cutoff on Google Charts Timeline visualization

Tags: google-visualization, visualization, timeline

The row labels for my timeline are being cutoff, but not all the time. It will look like this. Sometimes I'll refresh the page and the whole row label will display.

For a short term solution I've been using one letter/character as the label. I couldn't find any documentation on this issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6Vyg.jpg)

Comment: Open question on Google Groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/JXYbWNAEsYU

Comment: @jdv Thank you!